# UDF to paste recordset data in VBA

Tags: vba

Basically, I have managed to retrieve the data from database to recordset by means of 
rs=db.openrecordset(sql). How do I paste the data in the cell by UDF?  Someone suggested array formula. Then how do i change recordset data to array?  I know i can use copyfromrecordset . But it is not functioning in the UDF .

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet from the UDF?  Does it throw an error?  Do you just want to populate one cell or are you trying to return a multi-column/row dataset?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is that : i type =get_data() in a range of cells and click ctrl+shift+ enter . the data should be pasted into these cells.    What i am doing now is that : i use getRows method to change recordset to 2D array, but for some reason, i can only get the first row of the database, the sql is correct..

Comment: Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID,Date,Price,CMF,Ticker FROM SGXIO_Database  WHERE cmf Between 0 And 43 And contract Between #1/1/1900# And #1/1/2099# And Date Between #1/1/1900# And #1/1/2099# And price is not null")

 Dim arr As Variant
 arr = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
 MsgBox (rs.RecordCount)
 'bdd is the function name
bdd = arr




Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

Comment: Ok, I see. Since you want multiple rows and columns, `CopyFromRecordset` should work fine ... it's what I always use.  I feel like I'm missing something here.  Do you want different queries to run depending on which cell you CSE-paste the get_data() function?

Comment: I am using user defined function which i am not suppose to use any method to manipulate any other cells.  What i am doing now is to change recordset data to array format and use the array formula to call my function. I am solving most of it except that after using the recordset.movelast  and recordset.count and recordset.movefirst method. recordset.getrows only return the first row of data..

Comment: Ok. I think i cant use movelast in the UDF. =(.

Comment: You might have to loop through each record, and then loop through each field, of the recordset and add each value to your array variable as you go.  Since you've done `.moveLast`...`.moveFirst` to get the record count, it makes sense that it's only returning the first record.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with Excel 2003, ADO 2.8:

```
Function getArray(strSql As String) As Variant
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    getArray = ""

    Set rs = getRs(strSql)
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        Do
            For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                getArray = getArray & CStr(.Fields(i).Value) & " "
            Next i
            getArray = getArray & vbLf
            .MoveNext
        Loop Until .EOF = True
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

It loops through all the rows/fields of a recordset and returns an "array" of values.  It can be used as a workbook function without CSE.

This is how I'm making my db connection:

```
Function getRs(strSql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCn As String

    strCn = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    Set getRs = New ADODB.Recordset
    getRs.Open strSql, strCn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
End Function
```

And this is a sample of how I could retrieve some data using `getArray()` based on criteria from one cell and return the results into another (single) cell.

```
Function getEmpDataByLastName(strLastName As String) As Variant
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = ""
    strSql = strSql & "SELECT BusinessEntityID, PersonType, FirstName, COALESCE(MiddleName,'') AS MiddleName "
    strSql = strSql & "FROM Person.Person "
    strSql = strSql & "WHERE LastName = '" & strLastName & "' "
    strSql = strSql & "ORDER BY FirstName "

    getEmpDataByLastName = getArray(strSql)
End Function
```